# django rest framework nested modelserializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-rest-framework

this is realted to my other question
[django-rest-framework, multitable model inheritance, ModelSerializers and nested serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048595/django-rest-framework-multitable-model-inheritance-modelserializers-and-nested)

In django rest framework we can define nested model serializer like so

```
class OtherModelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    mybasemodel_set = MyBaseModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OtherModel
```

when we create an OtherModelSerializer,  the MyBaseModelSerializer is instantiated before `__init__` is run.
I believe this is the case because if I override the `__init__()` of MyBaseModelSerializer and check "instance", it is None.

**My question is when and how does `MyBaseModelSerializer` get passed the queryset or instance for `mybasemodel_set`?**

My goal here is to override what happens when we do this.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
mybasemodel_set = MyBaseModelSerializer(many=True)
```

Will initialize an instance of class `MyBaseModelSerializer` and pass `many=True` as parameter.

---

How does MyBaseModelSerializer get passed the queryset or instance?

I am not 100% sure what are you trying to do but most probably

```
class MyBaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     def to_representation(self, instance):
         pass
```

Is the function you are looking for. You will be given an instance and expected to return serialized data.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Answer (score 0):

While Instantiating, `MyBaseModelSerializer` does not have access to the queryset or instance of `mybasemodel_set`. It is only aware of its parent serializer (`OtherModelSerializer`).

The queryset or instance for `mybasemodel_set` is passed when `OtherModelSerializer` is initialized with data, such as during serialization or deserialization.
At this point, `OtherModelSerializer` retrieves the related objects for `mybasemodel_set` based on the provided instance or queryset.

If you want to override the behavior of `MyBaseModelSerializer` when it receives the related objects for `mybasemodel_set`, you can override methods like `to_representation()` or `to_internal_value()` within `MyBaseModelSerializer`.