# Serializing multiple inheritance models in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-models, multiple-inheritance, django-serializer

I have this model structure:

```
class Main (models.Model):
    name=models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    ...
class Category (Main):
    type=models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    ...
class SubCategory1(Category):
     charasteristic=models.Charfield(max_length=60)
     ...
class SubCategory2(Category):
     charasteristic=models.Charfield(max_length=60)
```

That is, there is one parent from which one children inherits, from which, in turn, multiple childrens inherit.
For the API, I would like to show a complete structure in the json, from grandparent to every grandson. I mean, if I use the following serializer:

```
class Subcategory1_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Subcategory1
        fields=("__all__")
```

it returns something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":
        "type":
        "charasteristic":
     },
]
```

But this forces me to create a serializer for every single Subcategory. I want to get it in an automatic way.

I've tried accessing via **subclasses**, I took a look at some proposals about Polymorphism (but I get lost) and I have tried to redefine inheritance in terms of OneToOne relationships, but I still cannot solve it (and it complicates data introduction from the admin panel).
Any help would be great,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think another problem might be how the receiver end would handle heterogeneous data. Inheritance is a strong concept, but does not fit very well with data, especially data in databases. Inheritance is likely most powerful as a ["template method"](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method), not that much to combine things that are essentially different.

Comment: Thanks for your point @willeM_VanOnsem , I'll take a look at the template method you mentioned. I have already solved the issue as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42282447/23148243 . Great community